# Pass param to a windows application without expand environment variable value

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, parameters

My Application accept some params that I use to execute a query on a database and then export retrieved data to a file.
All work fine but when I pass special params like `%temp%` param value is expanded as environment variable value: `C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Temp`.

This behaviour ca be reproduced with a simple `test.bat` script:

```
echo %1
```

launching

```
test.bat %temp1%
```

result is:

```
%temp1%
```

but launching:

```
test.bat %temp%
```

result is:

```
C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Temp
```

same result if I use quotes or prefix to %temp%

```
test.bat "PM:%temp%"
```

result is:

```
"PM:C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Local\Temp"
```

There is a way to use this params without os environment variable expansion?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/501528/prevent-setx-to-expand-an-environment-variable

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, i have tried this solution but i need to quote params (to handle space character): in this way `"^%temp^%"` return `^%temp^%` and not `%temp%` but `"%temp%"` is expanded.

Comment: If test.bat is `@echo %~1` then `test.bat "^%temp^%"` show `%temp%`. Tested on Win 8.1